# Detecting a specific character string

Tags: string, go, replace, trim

Recently, I had a school project that made me struggle for a week.
I really need help.

My program takes a string input and modifies it to return another string in its upper or lower case version, so far it works. But when I put in :
"This is so exciting (up, 2)" the output stays the same when it should be "This is SO EXCITING"
My point is to be able to handle the case : (up, n), knowing that the word followed by "(up)" must be capitalized.
If below you will find the concerned function.

Thanks in advance !

```
// modifyUp converts words before (up) to uppercase
func modifyUp(line string) string {
    words := strings.Fields(line)
    var numWords int
    var numbers int

    for i, word := range words {
        if strings.HasSuffix(word, "(up)") && i > 0 {
            // Convert word(s) to uppercase
            numWords = 1
            if strings.Contains(word, ",") {
                // Handle comma-separated words
                numbers, _ = strconv.Atoi(strings.TrimSuffix(strings.Split(word, ",")[1], ")"))
                word = strings.TrimSuffix(word, fmt.Sprintf(",%d)", numbers))
                numWords += numbers
            } else {
                word = strings.TrimSuffix(word, "(up)")
            }
            // Convert preceding word(s) to uppercase
            for j := i - numWords + 1; j <= i; j++ {
                if j >= 0 {
                    words[j] = strings.ToUpper(words[j])
                }
            }
            // Replace modified word with original word
            words[i-numWords+1] = word
        }
    }
    return strings.Join(words, " ")
```

Comment: strings.HasSuffix(word, "(up)") doesn't detect "(up, 2)".

Comment: Try the regex `"\\(up, (\\d+)\\)"` and group 1 will have the number

Comment: It's already done. Thanks for all !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found another way

```
func modifyUp(line string) string {
    words := strings.Fields(line)
    //var numWords int
    var numbers int

    for i, word := range words {
        if word == "(up," && i < len(words)-1 {
            ok := splitWord(words[i+1])
            if ok {
                wr := words[i+1]
                numbers, _ = strconv.Atoi(wr[:len(wr)-1])
                words[i], words[i+1] = "", ""
                for j := i - 1; j >= 0; j-- {
                    if numbers == 0 {
                        break
                    } else {
                        words[j] = strings.ToUpper(words[j])
                        numbers--
                    }
                }
            }
            break
        }
        if word == "(up)" && i > 0 {
            words[i-1] = strings.ToUpper(words[i-1])
            words[i] = ""
        }
    }

    return strings.Join(words, " ")
}
```

Thank all you for contibutions

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you are checking for specifically `(up)` which will not detect `(up, 2)`. An easy way to check this is that you can throw in an `fmt.Println(word)` at the start of the for loop to validate each word you're checking. In the case of `This is so exciting (up, 2)`, you get

```
This
is
so
exciting
(up,
2)
```

As you can see, `(up,` is found instead of `(up)`. On top of that, `2)` is separated from the check.

If we're keeping the same logic that you currently have, a quick fix for this is as followed:

```
func modifyUp(line string) string {
    words := strings.Fields(line)
    var numWords int

    for i, word := range words {
        if (strings.HasSuffix(word, "(up)") || strings.HasSuffix(word, "(up,")) && i > 0 {
            // Convert word(s) to uppercase
            numWords = 1
            if strings.Contains(word, ",") {
                var numbers int

                // Handle comma-separated words
                numbers, _ = strconv.Atoi(strings.TrimRight(words[i+1], ")"))

                words[i] = ""
                words[i+1] = ""
                numWords = numbers
            } else {
                words[i] = ""
            }

            // Convert preceding word(s) to uppercase
            for j := i - numWords; j <= i; j++ {
                words[j] = strings.ToUpper(words[j])
            }
        }
    }
    return strings.Join(words, " ")
}
```

I made some extra changes to the code to get it to work once you parsed the up correctly. You can also drop `words[i-numWords+1] = word` since you're already replacing it in the conversion.

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any following up questions.

Comment: Hello i have another question in the last code line i added `return strings.TrimSpace(strings.Join(words, " "))` beacause after replacing the "(up)" occurence the function add a whiteSpace and two whiteSpace with "(up,n)" this amking me mad.

Comment: I'm not sure you have a question but that's a good catch. The reason why there's white space is that we are setting the "(up) or (up,n)" as empty space shown. A cleaner version of the code is if you were to remove those from the words array instead the following code words[i] = "" or words[i+1] = ""